# How to convert hex string to bytes16

Tags: solidity

I am using provable service for getting api result from a third party api.
The api returns a hex string as a result but I need to convert it to bytes16.
I have tried using shift operations for conversion but it doesn't work.
Here is my code snippet.

```
function stringh(string memory x) public view returns(bytes16 fc) {
    bytes memory bts = bytes(x);
    bytes memory f = new bytes(16);
    for(uint k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
        int8 b = p_util_hexdigit[uint8(bts[2*k])];
        f[k] =  byte(b << 4);
        b = p_util_hexdigit[uint8(bts[2*k + 1])];
        f[k] |= byte(b);
    }
    

    assembly {
          fc := mload(add(f, 16))
    }
}
```

How can I figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `mload(add(f, 16))`. The first 32 bytes are the length of `f`, so you have to skip those 32 bytes.

```
    assembly {
          fc := mload(add(f, 32))
    }
```